# Is boost::property_map operator [] O(1) time complexity in this code?

Tags: performance, boost, boost-graph

I am new to boost and also boost graph library. Could anyone explain what is the implementation behind the property_map and what is the time-complexity of the operator [] in the following code?

Thanks!

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  typedef adjacency_list<listS, listS, directedS,
    property<vertex_name_t, std::string> > graph_t;
  graph_t g;
  graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor u = add_vertex(g);
  property_map<graph_t, vertex_name_t>::type name_map = get(vertex_name, g);
  name_map[i] = "Joe";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property map by giving an [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) to it. So the time and space complexity is probably the same as the underlying [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html). You might want to look deeper into the STL documentation of a [Sorted Associative Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/SortedAssociativeContainer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered this myself and find it odd that boost::graph documentation doesn't make this clear as questions such as this are highly relevant to performance critical algorithms/applications.

In summary I believe the answer is yes, it is O(1) time complexity.  My reasoning follows.

Since the [property map concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) are just concepts, it makes no guarantees about the complexity.  So we have to look at adjacency_list's implementation of a property map to know its complexity.   I believe the relevant code is found in [boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp); search for "Vertex Property Maps".

```
template <class Graph, class ValueType, class Reference, class Tag>
struct adj_list_vertex_property_map
  : public boost::put_get_helper<
      Reference,
      adj_list_vertex_property_map<Graph, ValueType, Reference, Tag>
    >
{
  typedef typename Graph::stored_vertex StoredVertex;
  typedef ValueType value_type;
  typedef Reference reference;
  typedef typename Graph::vertex_descriptor key_type;
  typedef boost::lvalue_property_map_tag category;
  inline adj_list_vertex_property_map(const Graph* = 0, Tag tag = Tag()): m_tag(tag) { }
  inline Reference operator[](key_type v) const {
    StoredVertex* sv = (StoredVertex*)v;
    return get_property_value(sv->m_property, m_tag);
  }
  inline Reference operator()(key_type v) const {
    return this->operator[](v);
  }
  Tag m_tag;
};
```

I believe this is the property map that is used for internal properties for an adjacency_list that is instantiated with a ListS VertexList type, as in your example.  You can see that the operator[] takes a Graph::vertex_descriptor which appears to be some handle, maybe an iterator, and accesses the property structure directly without lookup, `sv->m_property`, thus constant time.  The call to `get_property_value()` appears to be for property tag resolution when you have multiple properties associated with each vertex; in your case you only have one.  Tag lookup is typically also constant time.

Instantiating a adjacency_list with properties with a VecS VertexList type also appears to give O(1) time complexity in property map lookup.  The type used there appears to be `vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map` and the opearator[] uses the Graph::vector_descriptor in what appears to be an index into a vector of properties per vertex, thus O(1).

In retrospect, I suppose I would expect that because the library works so hard to be performant, it would ensure that this is also performant.